# About using functor to reduce problem into the category Sets

Tags: category-theory

In the [answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80797/magic-square-of-fibered-products-vague-unclear), the author said

> Now as for the proof of the Lemma, just use the Yoneda Lemma to reduce it to the case of the category of sets, where you can really see this equation immediately.

Is it suggesting that to prove any proposition in a category $\mathcal{C}$, we can always assume $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of sets, and just show in this case the proposition is true?

Comment: Hint : the Yoneda embedding is a fully faithful functor preserving limits.

Comment: Remark: You don't have to use the Yoneda Lemma, you can also prove the isomorphism of fiber products directly.

Comment: @Pece And thus it _reflects_ limits as well, which is the important bit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in you question about assuming $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets is not precise, so I don't think one can say whether it's true or false. But, with respect to the situation in the question you linked to, it can be made precise. Say you have a commutative square of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$

$\begin{matrix}X\rightarrow&X_1\\\\\downarrow&\downarrow\\\\X_2\rightarrow&Y\end{matrix}$

and you want to prove that this diagram is cartesian, meaning that the morphisms $p:X\rightarrow X_1,q:X\rightarrow X_2$ realize $X$ as $X_1\times_YX_2$. By Yoneda, this is equivalent to the statement that the diagram of contravariant $\mathrm{Hom}$ functors

$\begin{matrix}h_X\rightarrow&h_{X_1}\\\\\downarrow&\downarrow\\\\h_{X_2}\rightarrow&h_Y\end{matrix}$

arising from the first diagram is cartesian, which in turn means that for each object $S$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the diagram of sets

$\begin{matrix}X(S)\rightarrow&X_1(S)\\\\\downarrow&\downarrow\\\\X_2(S)\rightarrow&Y(S)\end{matrix}$

obtained by applying $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(S,-)$ to the original diagram, is cartesian. Now, in specific instances, such as the one in the question you reference, the morphisms in the original square are purely categorical in their definition (i.e. they make sense in any category for which the relevant constructions, like products, can be made, an example being the diagonal morphism), and if the Yoneda functor $X\rightsquigarrow h_X$ gives you the corresponding categorical morphisms in the category of contravariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to sets, then, if you've proved that such a diagram is cartesian in sets, you get cartesian-ness of the third diagram above for each object $S$, and therefore for the original diagram (in $\mathcal{C}$).

EDIT: As Martin Brandenburg indicates in his comment, it's not necessary to know about Yoneda's lemma to understand this. If one just thinks of the universal property of the fiber product (as a triple consisting of an object and two arrows), then one finds that the top diagram is cartesian if and only if the bottom diagram of sets is cartesian for each $S\in\mathcal{C}$.